# Vimperator: use hints without <CR> (possibly by forcing uniqueness)

Tags: hints, vimperator

[To clarify, I am using hints of near-home-row characters.]

Vimperator sometimes forces you to hit `<CR>` in order to complete hints.  This is very flow-breaking, especially since the Return key is not actually near the home row with my other hint characters.

I noticed this usually happened when a hint is not unique, e.g. if `f`, `fa` are possible hints, then selecting `f` requires typing `f<CR>`.

Is there a way to avoid this, possibly by changing a setting or modifying the hint selection algorithm to avoid non-unique hints?

Comment: I'm sorry for bumping an old question but I am currently facing the same problem. Does anyone has a solution to suggest?

Answer (score 0):

You can set `'hinttimeout'` to some small number, like 500 (it's measured in milliseconds; default is 0, i.e. no timeout). This will make Vimperator follow a non-unique hint if you don't type for the specified amount of type.